# Racket: lazy evaluation within some scope

Tags: racket, lazy-evaluation

Racket provides a [language extension](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/) for lazy evaluation that simply requires a `#lang lazy` header in the beginning of some file to change the evaluation strategy throughout the file.

However, this standard approach allows only a course level of granularity; A finer approach is needed to confine lazy evaluation to some defined scope.

**Does Racket provide some standard approach to confining a lazy evaluation strategy to some scope?** I'm looking for something like the following:

```
(eval-lazy (+ 2 2)) ;; only available by explicit or implicit call-by-need
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#lang lazy` is a completely different language than `#lang racket`. Yes, you can mix and match some parts, but it can get messy dealing with lazy values from `#lang lazy` in a `#lang racket` module.

Every scheme, thus also racket, has `delay` and `force`:

```
(define promise (delay (+ 2 2)))
(force promise) ; ==> 4
```

However that is just syntax sugar anyway since you can do it like this:

```
(define promise (thunk (+ 2 2)))
(promise) ; ==> 4
```

And of course `thunk` is just syntax sugar for anonymous function with no arguments:

```
(define promise (lambda () (+ 2 2)))
(promise) ; ==> 4
```

Now `delay` actually is slightly more complex since if you call these functions it will run the expression every time. To prevent that we memoize the result. Here I'll implement your `eval-lazy` as a macro:

```
(define ^not-calculated (list #f)) ; unique value
(define-syntax eval-lazy
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expression)
     (let ((value ^not-calculated))
       (lambda ()
         (when (eq? ^not-calculated value)
           (set! value expression))
         value)))))
```

As with the `thunk` and `lambda` just calling the result will force it.

**Streams**

Racket provides a [stream library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=tsreams) which can be used to do 90% of all algorithms in a way where you do abstract each step as it's own process where you can compose them together without getting the penalty of lists. Streams are just delayed values in `cons` popularized in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)

Comment: Some comments: (1) `#lang lazy` was made to be very similar to plain racket, and to make it easy to cooperate with plain racket (eg, uses racket promises); (2) therefore, dealing with lazy values is not too messy; (3) it *is* possible to work at a smaller granularity with a submodule; (4) no, implementing promises properly is *definitely not* "slightly more complex", it is *much more* — to see that I'd suggest looking at the racket implementation, but even better: your example code demonstrates some subtleties, since it creates closures that are never gone and therefore always leaks memory.

Comment: @EliBarzilay 1-3: So using a lazy library gives you promises that you might need to force. Well that's slightly easier than I thought. 4: That's probably why `delay` is a Scheme primitive in the first place. SICP probably have the same leak in their video. I love reading racket code so I'll have a look when I have some spare time. It seems `delay` is both a procedure and a macro from it's expansion.

Comment: Well, (1-2) it also gives you `!!` and `!!!` to force values recursively; (4) no, it's a primitive for other reasons, but it's easy to mis-implement it in a way that leads to memory leaks, I don't remember what's in the videos, but look for "forget unneeded env" in 4.2 to see one subtle-but-easy-to-see problem, and see [the racket source](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/master/racket/collects/racket/private/promise.rkt) for pointers and for the code.